# DiscordPy clear hybrid command - Only works properly with prefix, not as slash command

Tags: discord.py

Good day folks. I have the following clear command:

```
#clear command
@commands.hybrid_command(name = "clear", with_app_command = True, description = "Need to clear?",ephemeral = True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(self,ctx: commands.Context, limit:int = None):
    if limit == None:
        limit = 5
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit+1)
    #await ctx.reply(f'Successfully cleared {limit} messages.')
```

The command works properly deleting messages. However when I call it as a slash command, it will clear the messages but return a "The application did not respond" message.

I've tried using ctx.reply and ctx.send on the commented line but none of them do the trick.

I also get a "In message_reference: Unknown message".

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "The application did not respond" message.

For application commands, you have to respond within 3 seconds. As you are clearing messages beforehand (which is an API call that may take some time to complete) you're probably exceeding this deadline.

If what you're doing is slow, you must first `defer` and then `followup` afterwards. The library can handle this automatically for you in hybrid commands using [`Context.typing()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=typing#discord.ext.commands.Context.typing).

Comment: Legend, I added the following 
```
await ctx.defer(ephemeral=True)
```
and its working now.